# How to show two tables records in one foreach?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

How can I show two tables's records in one foreach at sametime via **Entity Framework**?

**My tables:**

[image: tables content]
**My code:**

```
var transfer = dbContext.tbl_Transfer.Where(a => a.GeciciServisID == x.GeciciServisID);
```

Both tables have **GeciciServisID**, so I would like to get them with **GeciciServisID**.
Then I would like to process records like

**foreach (var x in transfer){}**

Is there a simple way to do it?

Thanks you.

## UPDATE:

jim tollan put the solution but,
I explained wrong my question.
I mean, as migrate or as merge O_o two table with code.
for example we have two table (as you see)

**Table A / Table B**

1. ABC  / 1.ABS
2. EBS  / 2. EDC
3. RAW  / 3. HTML

and then foreach:

- ABC
- ABS
- EBS
- EDC
- RAW
- HTML

I think my question is clear to understand now... :)

## FINAL:

[Jim Tollan finished.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20287677/2426367)

Thanks.

Comment: ok, this is really just going a level deeper and creating an anonymous object, gropued on the GeciciServisID. if you could explain fully the properties required from each table, then i'll add a second section to explain the update (i.e. will keep the original answer and then put an exapnaded update as an edit)

Comment: thanks jim, I need (int)EkipID, (nvarchar)Semt, (nvarchar)Adres from both table.

Comment: ok, for this, we need to use linq projection... let me ponder, tho there are a variety of way to do this, some with multi step setup (using intermediary anonymous types) and another using a single monolithic linq statement. my preferred approach for future viewers of this thread would be the stepped approach.

Comment: ok, update in place -not slinky, but functional - enjoy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ercin, based on Esa's answer, here's the c# version:

```
var results = 
    tbl_EkTransfer
    .Join(tbl_Transfer, tt => tt.GeciciServisId, tkt => tkt.GeciciServisId, 
        (newtt, newtkt) => new
        {
            newtt, 
            newtkt
        })
        .Where(x => x.newtkt.GeciciServisId == 1); // etc
```

you'd then iterate doing:

```
foreach (var result in results)
{
    var test1 = result.newtkt.GeciciServisId;
    var test2 = result.newtt.GeciciServisId;
}
```

**[Edit]** - as per the OP amendment to the question.

**Amendment**

This implementation is a very simple multi-step approach, rather than trying to create a linq super complex implementation. Literally, we take the two IQueryable datasets and add them to a new `TransferClass()`. It's not complex and is purely a starting point to experiment with. We can't union the structures as they are different, so we adopt a holding class to project into. Anyway, the update:

the new holding class (a sort of viewModel):

```
public class TransferResult
{
    public int GeciciServisId { get; set; }
    public int EkipID { get; set; }
    public string Semt { get; set; }
    public string Adres { get; set; }
    public string SourceTable { get; set; }
}
```

the implementation:

```
// create a holding class collection
var results = new List<TransferResult>();

// add the results from first table
results.AddRange(tbl_EkTransfer.Where(x => x.GeciciServisId == 5)
    .Select(x => new TransferResult()
{
    GeciciServisId = x.GeciciServisId,
    Adres = x.Adres,
    Semt = x.Semt,
    EkipID = x.EkipID,
    SourceTable = "tbl_EkTransfer"
}));

// add the results from second table
results.AddRange(tbl_Transfer.Where(x => x.GeciciServisId == 5)
    .Select(x => new TransferResult()
{
    GeciciServisId = x.GeciciServisId,
    Adres = x.Adres,
    Semt = x.Semt,
    EkipID = x.EkipID,
    SourceTable = "tbl_Transfer"
}));

// now one row per joined result set
foreach (var result in results.OrderBy(x => x.Adres))
{
    var test1 = result.Adres; // etc
}
```

That's really all there is to it. This does take away the linq join but sacrifices nothing to achieve the result. Given more time, I'm certain we could still use a join and do the operation in a single hit, but that's an essay for another day...

Comment: Ah. Beaten me to it. My version is using the more SQL like notation of Linq, but functionally I think it's doing the same. It is missing the dbContext object from the OPs sample code though. I'll delete mine though, no point having both present.

Comment: good point, was *thinking* linq objects in my head, but yes, obviously, each tbl(object) would be prefixed by dbContext!! [edit] - no, keep yours as not everyone is *into* the linq method chain style -diverstity rules

Comment: I love sexy answers, thanks :) I need time to understand this :]

Answer (score 3):

You can join the tables like this. Sorry it's in VB.Net but someone can probably translate it to C# if needed:

```
Dim results = From ek in tbl_EkTransfer 
              Join t in tbl_Transfer on ek.GeciciServisId = t.GeciciServisId
              Where... (what you want)
              Select ek, t

For Each result in results
  ' ...
Next
```

Comment: looks like a fine answer to me and i'm certain the OP will be able to refactor fine for c#

Comment: Thanks for the possible solution. I tried converter vb to c but not works. btw: vote up requires 15 rep. Sorry.

Comment: Put the code as it is now to your question so we can see it. It should not be so different in c#.

Comment: Converter failed, I mean. :) http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp/

Comment: What is the etiquette for providing the conversion here? I've converted @Esa's code to C# - should I edit? or post as another answer? It's not my answer, so almost feel like it should be an edit?

Comment: @Obsidian please post or comment it as way to possible answer. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Based on Esa's answer, I have manually converted to C#:

```
var results = from ek in dbContext.tbl_EKTransfer
              where //...(what you want)
              select ek.ServisID
var results = from t in dbContext.tbl_Transfer
              where // ...(what you want)
              select t.ServisID;

results = results.Union(results2);

foreach (var result in results)
{

}
```

**Update**

I've updated the sample to show getting the values as you specify in your update. For this I have assumed you want a single, shared value from both - with a shared datatype.

If you want multiple columns, you need to replace the `select` line with `select new() {ek.ServisID, ek.TransferId}` where the values specified are the values you want. Be aware though, that both queries need to output exactly the same anonymous type - that is, they both must have the same properties, with the same name, and the same datatype.

You can get around different names by aliasing in the new: `new {ID = ek.SomeOtherColumn}`

Comment: +1'nd you as it's a fair slant on the same issue. but see update above, tougher call now :)

Comment: Yeah. I'd probably go Union in that case. Updated my code to reflect the change.

Comment: obs -the union would of course work if both lists were projected into the same type!

Comment: Agreed. Both anonymous types would require to be exactly the same. in terms of property names and data types.